# html table not populated using knockout.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have web application where I'm trying to populate my html table using knockout.js but my table is still empty. My data is being called via ajax. jQuery and Knockout.js were all referenced to my page. Here's the code;

**HTML**

```
 <table id="payment_schedule">
            <thead>
                <tr class="tableHeader">
                    <th width="50px">
                        Index
                    </th>
                    <th width="50px">
                        Due Date
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-bind="foreach: paymentSchedules">
                    <td data-bind="text: Index"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Month"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**JavaScript functions**

```
 function GetComputation() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/UnitSearch/CalculateMortgage',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
                viewModel.paymentSchedules(data.PaymentSchedules);
        }
    });
}
var data = [];
var viewModel = {
    paymentSchedules: ko.observableArray(data)
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**data returned from ajax**

[image]

Comment: Are there any JS errors in your browser console? When do you call the `GetCumputation` method?

Comment: it should work fine! Where you call GetCumputation() in your code?

Comment: @nemesv I checked both firebug and Chrome Console but no errors shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should work fine. You haven't shown where you are calling the `GetComputation` function but here's a full working example.

Controllers:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class UnitSearchController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CalculateMortgage()
    {
        var data = new 
        {
            PaymentSchedules = new[] 
            {
                new { Index = "Reservation Fee", Month = "23-Jan-13" },
                new { Index = "Reservation Fee", Month = "25-Jan-13" },
            }
        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Index view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="payment_schedule">
        <thead>
            <tr class="tableHeader">
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: paymentSchedules">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Index"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Month"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [];
        var viewModel = {
            paymentSchedules: ko.observableArray(data)
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        function GetComputation() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/UnitSearch/CalculateMortgage',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    viewModel.paymentSchedules(data.PaymentSchedules);
                }
            });
        }

        // I am calling the GetComputation function immediately in this example
        // to populate the table with data but you could call it whenever you want
        GetComputation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example I am calling the `GetComputation` immediately but you could adapt the code and invoke it whenever you want. Also notice that I have applied the `data-bind="foreach: paymentSchedules"` on the `<tbody>` and not the `<tr>` element.

Comment: Shouldn't the method be of return type JsonResult instead of ActionResult?  Assuming GetComputation is being called, I also believe the real problem is the foreach on the incorrect element.

Comment: @JoelCochran, no the return type shouldn't be `JsonResult` simply because `JsonResult` derives from `ActionResult` and it is better not to specialize the return types of your actions.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested it, but can you try moving the data-bind
`data-bind="foreach: paymentSchedules"` to tbody instead of the tr?

The foreach knockout documentation does the same. Refer http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html